# How do generic http requests work in Angular?

Tags: angular

When you have an http client action, like for example this.http.get, what does having a generic type do? Like if I did this.http.get(url);, is this going to ensure that everything requested from the url is of that type, and if not will it throw an error?

Is there any difference between

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
    );
}
```

And doing this:

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
    );
}
```

Am I correct in believing that the two examples have the same effect, because the bottom example's method signature specifies the Observable's type? So isn't the bottom example also being genericized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference whatsoever. The same data will be returned in both cases. The genetic type, ensures type safety for the rest of the application.

By setting the generic you are setting an expectation for the rest of the application if what to expect from the call and how to handle it.

Comment: So in the bottom example, the generic type is still being set because of the method signature then, right? I wasn't sure if I needed to be as specific as the top example, i.e include the type in the this.http part as well

Comment: You don't need to as typescript is changed to javascript which is not type safe in runtime. It's better though to go with option one, for cleaner code and less errors.

Comment: Without generic, it's as if you are using the any type.